What is the difference between gpaste and gpaste-2 packages on Ubuntu?
After upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04.1, the package gpaste has been uninstalled automatically by the upgrade process, and is no longer available in the repository.
However a new package called gpaste-2 is now available. Can someone tell what is the reason behind this? Searching on the web didn't bring up anything.

Inspecting the changelog for gpaste-2, you'll see that it is still built from the gpaste source package, but was renamed:
gpaste (42.1-1) experimental; urgency=medium

  * New upstream version 42.1
  * Upstream renamed it gpaste-2
  * Switched to meson build system

But I think this was just a result of some confusion on the part of the package maintainer. The library was indeed renamed, it is now libgpaste-2 instead of libgpaste, as can be seen in the upstream announcement post. But I suppose the maintainer might have seen the overhaul (not just a new library, but update to GTK4 for the preferences GUI, using a new build system, and using a new version number format), and thought that the entire software had been renamed.
